# Massive ORM dynamic Where filtering

Tags: .net, orm, massive

Since there is not much documentation on this, could someone tell if there is a way of filtering data dynamically, given that there are lot of filter options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually really simple if anyone has the same question, if there is a better way please let me know:

```
        string query = "select * from pandas where panda_id = :0";
        List<object> parameters = new List<object>();
        parameters.Add(15162210);

        //  Apply filter
        if(shouldSearchByName)
        {
            query += " and name = :1";
            parameters.Add("Super Panda");
        }

        // Return the data
        return DB.Current.Query( query, args:parameters.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this not better be done in SQL, rather than manipulating your sql with string methods? There are a bunch of options explained [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). The simplest of them is as follows...

```
select * from table1
where (col1 = :0 or :0 is null)
and (col2 = :1 or :1 is null)
and (col3 = :2 or :2 is null)
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: I don't think you can get this to work as well in Oracle

Comment: But you're not using Oracle?

Comment: I actually am, I was thinking on something similar, but it was said that when joining results the performance for this solution is bad, or something similar, this was some time ago :) But if not for oracle, this is a great answer.